# One-to-many relation based on multiple key (conditional) in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, relational-database, one-to-many

So I have

```
class User
{
   ...
   public virtual ICollection<Book> AlreadyRead {get; set;} 
}

class Book
{
   ...
   public virtual User Owner {get; set;}
   public bool AlreadyRead {get; set;}
}
```

So what I need is that `User.AlreadyRead` return me `Books` by this `User`, where `AlreadyRead == true`

I tryed this bindings

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
            .HasRequired(b => b.Owner)
            .WithMany(u => u.AlreadyRead)
```

But in that way `User.AlreadyRead` return all books, but I need only books with `AlreadyRead == true`;

Is it possible to solve this problem using mapping, but not additional property with `Where` logic?

I just need to be able to add condition to the mapping which will check `AlreadyRead == true`

Comment: Can you update question with code inside `User` Class

Comment: Sorry, my bad. User == Person

Comment: What is the problem you tried with the binding? i.e. modelbuilder statement you provided in question.

Comment: Is there already relationship between User and Book apart from AlreadyRead?

Comment: No, there is single relation. The problem that it return all books, but I need only readed books

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but I'm afraid is not possible include a condition in a relationship configuration. But, as a partial solution, I suggest you add a [`NotMapped`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#NotMapped) property to your `User` class. Your model would be like this:

```
public class User
{
   ...
   public virtual ICollection<Book>  Books{get; set;} 

  [NotMapped] 
  public IEnumerable<Book> AlreadyReadedBooks 
  { 
     get 
     { 
        return Books.Where(b=>b.AlreadyRead); 
     } 
  }
}

public class Book
{
  ...
  public virtual User Owner {get; set;}
  public bool AlreadyRead {get; set;}
}
```

And your relationship configuration would be like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
        .HasRequired(b => b.Owner)
        .WithMany(u => u.Books);
```

### Update:

The navegation properties are used to represent relationships between tables and to provide a way to navigate an association between two entity types. In your case, you are stablishing an one-to-many relationship between `Books` and `Users`, and it works because a foreign key is defined on the table that represents the many end of the relationship (`Books`).  When you stablish a relationship between two tables in a relational database,  you can't add a restriction as you want in the relationship, the same happens in Entity Framework when you declare navegation properties. That's way, if you need the  readed books of an specific user, you need to do a query.

Comment: Ok, but I'm curious to know why It's not possible to do that. I think virtual navigation properties acually working the same manner, so should be some real constraint to not allowin it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "the virtual navigation properties actually working the same manner". I have updated my answer. Hope this help you to understand better how they work

Comment: Yes, but what this navigation property (proxy list) inside - this is simple call like Books.Where(b => b.UserId == CURRENT_USER_ID). So I can't figure out, why it's not possible to specify additional constaints

Comment: I understand your point of view, but that breaks the concept of what it means a navigation property. which is (in this case) to get access to all the rows where is involved the current user in the Book table. If you restrict that, you are not properly representing the relationship between Users and Books.